# Dell Precision 3510 microphone?

Tags: laptop, microphone, device-manager

I have a Dell Precision 3510 laptop (about one year old). 
However, somehow I cannot find a camera.

In the device settings I see under Audio Inputs and Outputs only one item:
- Speakers / Headphones (RealTek Audio)

I would expect a microphone. When I select 'Scan for hardware changes', I do not see any difference.

How can I add the (builtin) microphone? (Mostly to use Skype). I'm almost sure it worked in the past and I cannot imagine this laptop does not have a microphone (it has a camera and some small holes next to it).

Comment: Yes, the two holes around the camera are the microphone. This might be a question of [drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en/en/frbsdt1/product-support/product/precision-m3510-workstation/drivers), but if the device has simply disappeared then it might be a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I switched it off in:

- Sound Settings control panel icon
- Menu item: Recording Devices.
- Tab 2: Recording
- Microphone array (Realtek Audio): Disabled

Than double click that item:
- Device usage: Don't use this audio device (disable)

This needs to be changed to:
- Use this device (Enable)

However, when I enable it, I hear even my own typing echoed through the speakers.

What also is strange, the device is not even mentioned in the device driver anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the microphone issue on these models. It was easier than you could imagine. With all the dell updates, it seems the Realtek software and driver take a hit. I looked and and decided to uninstall all the Realtek software, rebooted and then I could see my microphone was now working. Afterwards, I re-installed the Realtek along with the WaveAudio. It's been working since. Let me know if this works for you as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't try it anymore, but upvoted as it might help others.